# Is swimming more difficult under high hydrostatic pressure?

Tags: fluid-statics

The force required to displace water increases as hydrostatic pressure increases, causing things to be crushed at high depth. Is there a correlation where locomotion and mobility gets more and more difficult with depth, for aquatic animals?

Comment: Where did you find this? I don't believe the force required to displace water increases appreciably at for example a 1000 bar.

Comment: simply that objects are crushed, the opposite of displacing water (force against water), water instead crushes in on object

Comment: @Bar Pressure increases with depth, not viscosity

Comment: I only think I mentioned pressure in the question. I mostly just wondered, is there any correlation where mobility gets more difficult with depth, or (discounting all other factors) could a tuna fish swim as efficiently as 12000 meters like at 400 meters?

Comment: The hydrostatic pressure difference is 1000 atm at 12000 meters depth, and 40 atm at 400 meters. An increase by a factor of 25.